# Javascript dates not shown as equal, despite getTime() function showing the dates ARE equal

Tags: javascript

I read somewhere that you can't compare Javascript dates using the date objects, but that you could using the getTime().

This is mostly working for me, except for one date. This is my code:

```
if (d1.getTime() != d2.getTime()) {
    // Dates are not equal, new data present
    Logger.log(d1); // Fri Jul 17 08:15:14 GMT+02:00 2015
    Logger.log(d2); // Fri Jul 17 08:15:14 GMT+02:00 2015
}
```

To me, these look exactly equal.

The other 308 rows on the spreadsheet being parsed also show as equal.

== EDIT ==

Comparing the milliseconds of the date, they are in fact not equal. This is absurd, as if they are not equal, then the new date is inserted into CouchDB and that becomes the date to compare to on the next script run (without changing the date). So CouchDB in this case must be truncating milliseconds.

Comment: `getTime()` is accurate to the milliseconds but the logger output is accurate to the seconds only. How about `console.log( d1.getTime() )` and `console.log( d1.getTime() )` and checking if they're really equal?

Comment: @PraveenKumar He's not comparing objects.

Comment: Dates will be logged in the script's timezone.

Comment: @Juhana Then what are `d1` and `d2`? i.e., `typeof d1` and `typeof d2`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Does `.getTime()` return an object?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2643

Comment: @Juhana I sometimes lose my brain. `:P`

Comment: @Zach Smith,Its depened on logged timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be difference in milli seconds. Check following example for reference:

```js
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();
d2.setMilliseconds(d2.getMilliseconds() + 2);

console.log(+d1, +d2);
console.log(d1, d2);
console.log(+d1 === +d2);
```

Comment: This is a simulation showing why d1 and d2 looks same but are different.

Comment: Ah thanks. I see that this is also a hack of making sure they have the same milliseconds. which is helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use `getTime` you are getting a millisecond timestamps. So they would only be equal if they refer to the same millisecond timestamp. If you are interested in comparing their String representation:

```
d1.toString() === d2.toString()
```

**Edit**: Sorry, had wrong formats before.